# unable to load two page on same url using atmosphere in jhipster version 1.0.0

Tags: sockets, spring-mvc, atmosphere, jhipster

I have updated my project to the latest version of jhipster, that is 1.0.0 . In my project I am opening 2 different pages on the same url depending on user is logged in or not, that is, if user is logged in then home page is requested else index page is requested. When web socket with atmosphere framework is not used in this latest version jhipster project, it works fine but in case when web socket with atmosphere framework is used there are 2 cases:

- First case is that when user presses the enter button or F5 button to refresh the page, it does not enter to the StaticResourcesProductionFilter due to which our mapping is not bind i.e i have set our code in StaticResourcesProductionFilter file.
- Second case is when the user presses the Ctrl+F5 buttons to refresh the page, it enters the static resources and it works fine.

our code for mapping is :

```
 if ("/".equals(requestURI)) {         
 //System.out.println("requestURI"+requestURI);
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 String name = auth.getName();
 if(name.equals("anonymousUser")){
  requestURI = "/index.html";
 }
 else{
  requestURI = "/home.html";
 }
}
```

But i want to use my project web socket with atmosphere framework and in every case. Please help to find the solution for it so that I can use web socket as well as open 2 different pages on same url depending on user is logged in or not.